# Manage projects with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have 3 projects, that have base code and every projects have new icons, launch image and colors.

What is the best way to manage them all?

I tried to make workspace but collapse with strange Xcode behavior and spend 30 minutes to get back my last project details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to work on all three at once on one screen? If so, just open more than one desktop with mission control. Go to Mission Control and hover around the top right of screen and press the "+" button and a new desktop will be created. Just open another project there. To delete the desktop, hover around the top left of the desktop when you launch mission control and you'll see an "x" and that removes the second(or third) desktop.

Comment: NO, I am not, I want have same code for all 3 projects, but different app names, launch images, app icons